# How to look for a variable named the same as a string in Python

Tags: python

```
x=['a','b','c']
y=['d','e','f']
z=['g','h','i']
string='x'
```

#Now I would like to somehow get the list printed or returned by only using the string variable.

Comment: Consider explaining more

Comment: `print(eval(string))`

Comment: Use a `dict` with keys `'x'`, `'y'`, and `'z'` in the first place, instead of using three different variables: `d = {'x': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'y': ['d', 'e', 'f'], 'z': ['g', 'h', 'i']}`. Then you just use `d[string]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Answer (score 0):

Use `globals` or `locals`:

```py
x=['a','b','c']
y=['d','e','f']
z=['g','h','i']
string='x'

print(globals()[string])
```

```
['a','b','c']
```

Comment: Although this is technically exactly what he asked for it is important to point out that this is almost never the right solution to whatever design problem needs to be solved. Please just use a dictionary instead...

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple list and you want to print them based on some key it's best to use a dictionary.

```py
lstDic = {
    "x":['a','b','c'],
    "y":['d','e','f'],
    "y":['g','h','i']
}
string='x'
print(lstDic[string])
```